# Javascript function to validate contents of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here's what is asked:

*validItems(items) – this function receives a string array of items which are to be for a customer. The function returns an empty string indicating all item codes in the array are valid; otherwise the function returns the first invalid item code in the array. All item codes must be selected from the item codes provided. They are: IT00, O144, 6A1L, 4243, O3D5, 44SG, CE64, 54FS and 4422.*

This is what I've done so far:

```js
 function validItems(items) {
     
      var error = false;
    
      for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    
        if (error == false) {
    
          if (items[i] != "IT00" ||
            items[i] != "0144" ||
            items[i] != "6A1L" ||
            items[i] != "4243" ||
            items[i] != "O3D5" ||
            items[i] != "44SG" ||
            items[i] != "CE64" ||
            items[i] != "54FS" ||
            items[i] != "4422") {
    
            error = items[i];
    
          } else {
    
            error = false;
          }
        } else {
          if (error != false) {return error;} else {return "";}
        }
    
      }
    
    }
    
    var items = ["IT00","0144","6A1L"];
    alert(validItems(items));
```

It keeps on returning IT00. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple array based test like

```js
var validCodes = ['IT00', 'O144', '6A1L', '4243', 'O3D5', '44SG', 'CE64', '54FS', '4422'];

function validItems(items) {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (validCodes.indexOf(items[i]) == -1) {
      return items[i];
    }
  }
  return '';
}

var items = ["IT00", "O144", "6A1L"];
alert(validItems(items));
```

---

To make your code work

```js
function validItems(items) {

  var error = false;

  for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    console.log(items[i], error)

    if (error == false) {

      //need to use && since otherwise one value cann't satisfy all these conidtions
      if (items[i] != "IT00" && items[i] != "0144" && items[i] != "6A1L" && items[i] != "4243" && items[i] != "O3D5" && items[i] != "44SG" && items[i] != "CE64" && items[i] != "54FS" && items[i] != "4422") {
        //if current item is not matching assign it to the error and break the loop
        error = items[i];
        break;
        //you can really return from here, not need to use the error variable also
      }
    }
  }
  //this should be outside of the loop
  //if there is an errro return the error string
  if (error != false) {
    return error;
  } else {
    return "";
  }
  return '';
}
var items = ["IT00", "0144", "6A1L"];
alert(validItems(items));
```

Comment: ... you have 209k points and you did not put the if in an Array

Comment: @MichaelDibbets see the first solution.... the second was just a correction to original code

Answer (score 1):

What you'll notice here is that there is zero complexity. Each function below takes a couple arguments and does *one* simple task. It's very easy to see what each function does at first glance.

```js
// your data
const validItems = [
  "0144", "6A1L", "4243", "O3D5", "44SG", "CE64", "54FS", "4422"
];

// some reusable functions
const all = f => xs => xs.every(f);
const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x));
const neq = y => x => x !== y;
const indexOf = xs => x => xs.indexOf(x);
const elem = xs => comp(neq(-1))(indexOf(xs))

// your helpers
const validateItems = all(elem(validItems));

// test it out
console.log( validateItems(["0144", "6A1L"]) ); // true
console.log( validateItems(["0144", "CAKE"]) ); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code it is correct that it is outputting IT00.
You are using the OR selector which means if the string is IT00, then it is not 0144 or 6A1L. Your intention is to exclude ALL so you are looking for values which are not IT00 AND not 0144 ANd not 6A1L, etc. etc.

use the AND:

```
if (items[i] != "IT00" &&
    items[i] != "0144" &&
    items[i] != "6A1L" &&
    items[i] != "4243" &&
    items[i] != "O3D5" &&
    items[i] != "44SG" &&
    items[i] != "CE64" &&
    items[i] != "54FS" &&
    items[i] != "4422") {
```

When you understand the basic of this logic, also try to rewrite your code. An array of allowed values is for example a bit more tidy ;-)

Comment: Using an if statement is wrong. With a long list of items you do not want to edit a long tedious if statement... use an array.

Answer (score 0):

Your first item returns true on your if statement. If your first item is "ITOO", The first match of you make is:

```
items[i] != "0144"
```

your code then says

```
error = items[i]; //which is "ITOO"
```

and then you return

```
error
```

which is the first item "ITOO"

Answer (score 0):

Your Or condition should have "==" instead of "!=".

Which means -> If "the give code"  is same as "any of the recognized codes" then recognize it otherwise drop it.

Currently your condition means -> If "the given code"  is not same as "any of the recognized code" then recognize it. This condition will always be true

Answer (score 0):

You had some basic coding errors in your code.
I've modified your code and put in the comments where I saw room for improvement.

Basically your if else statements were redundant. If you simply exit the function by returning the faulty thing you already get the desired result.

No need to keep looping if we have found a mismatch.
In a function where you'd need to do additional checks after finding a fault you would use `break` and then do your logic on error if `error !== false`

```js
 function validItems(items) {
              // create a valid items array. This will make maintaining valid item codes easier. and keep your code readable.
              var valid = ["IT00","0144","6A1L","4243","O3D5","44SG","CE64","54FS","4422"];
              var error = false;
            
              for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                // Type safe test. Always use 3 === isntead of == your test would have returned true on eveyrthing.
                if (error === false) {
            
                  if(valid.indexOf(items[i]) === -1) {
                    // immedeately escape
                    return items[i];
            
                  } /*else {// Totally uneccesary
                    error = false;
                  }
                } else {
                  // not needed here. this also escaped your loop after first iteration.
                  if (error !== false) {return error;} else {return "";}
                }*/
              
              }
              // we return here because we know the loop is done then.
              return error;
            }
            
            var items = ["IT00","0144","6A1L"];
            alert(validItems(items));
```